# How does the blue color of starch solution change depending on temperature and what is the cause for this?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was doing a project for my school and im not sure the following answer is correct:

*"After adding iodine liquid to starch solution the colour turns blue. By heatig the mixture loses its colour. "*

I am not sure if that is fully correct, i also don't know what even is the cause for this change.

If anyone can check the answer and explain what would the cause be, i would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is correct. Iodine and starching solution are making a deep blue complex at room temperature. The reaction is part of an equilibrium, and it is slightly exothermic.  When heating an equilibrium at a higher temperature, the endothermic back-rection is favored. So this complex is destroyed and the solution contains only starch and iodine. The reaction is reversible. The blue complex is produced again when cooling the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, so if i understood correctly the blue color disappears because the iodine comes out of the starch helix while heating ?

Comment: You have perfectly understood.

Comment: Not entirely reversible, as starch slowly hydrolyzes, and faster at higher temperature, breaking into simple, clear, sugars.